# What, if anything, does it mean to be neither finite nor infinite for real numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this book which is said to be notoriously bad by my professor and the graduate T.A's and in a section titled "Series with Nonnegative Terms" the following statement appears:

> Every series $\Sigma{a_n}$ with $a_n \ge 0$ has a finite or infinite sum

I do assume the series is real. This appears near the beginning of the chapter introducing the integral test.

So the reasonable question is then, what can be said about the sum of a series $\Sigma{a_n}$ with $a_n < 0$

Is it not the case that the sum is finite or infinite? If so, what does that even mean? Is this just undefined or inconclusive? Perhaps a better question is, why is this statement important?

Comment: It means the sum of the series exists, in the set $\overline{\mathbb R}_+=[0,+\infty]$. (No idea how your "reasonable question" is related, though.)

Comment: @Did it would be like the same thing except factoring out a negative 1.

Comment: Sure, except that not every series has either all its entries positive or all its entries negative.

Comment: @GitGud I greatly appreciate everyone that offers their knowledge to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree it could have been worded better, although less briefly.  What the author is trying to say is that an infinite sum of nonnegative terms either converges to a finite value, or else diverges to infinity.  The same would be true for a series with nonpositive terms ( converges to a finite value or diverges to negative infinity ), but one cannot say the same if the terms are mixed, such as 
$
\sum \left( -1 \right) ^n
$

Comment: Okay that is much more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The limit might not exist. For example 
1-1+1-1+....

Comment: Arguably, for all $n\in \Bbb N, a_n\ge 0$.

Comment: The point being that when you mix terms your limit might not exist. When you have strictly positive terms, then the sequence of partial sums is increasing. Hence if it is bounded above it converges. Otherwise it is infinite.